# Change element positions by specific value in ArrayList (Android)

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a `ArrayList` of model class which has 3 different keys

`Feeds`, `Category` and `Tags`

They are mixed in the list

but I want to arrange them in specific ways

Like

> **Feeds related data needs to display first, then Category related data and then Tags related data**

Doea anyone has idea how to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property

Comment: @pete I have 3 fields to compare. I dont know how use comparator here

Comment: I suggest you create a base class with a int type member variable. Derive your 3 model classes from this and set type to a different value in each model. Then use the type variable in the sort operation.

Comment: Thanx for your help @Pete